# Как поймать weblib.error.DataNotFound?

Tags: python, исключения, grab

Есть код, который ищет графу salary на некоем сайте. В большистве случаев её нет и я получаю:

```
weblib.error.DataNotFound: Could not get first item for div[@class="-title"]//span[@class="salary"] query of class XpathSelector
```

Пытаюсь ловить через try - except, но я не смог поймать ни как DataNotFound, ни weblib.error.DataNotFound, ни просто error. Работа try - except продолжается через else и выводится traceback.

Мой код:

```
try:
    sal = i.select('div[@class="-title"]//span[@class="salary"]')
except Exception:
    jobinfo.update({'salary': 'Null'})
else:
    sal = int(sal.text())
    jobinfo.update({'salary':sal})
```

Traceback вызывает уже строка после else:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/shmulya/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/remoteokpars/parser.py", line 33, in <module>
  sal = int(sal.text())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selection/base.py", line 103, in text
  sel = self.one()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selection/base.py", line 86, in one
  raise DataNotFound(m)
weblib.error.DataNotFound: Could not get first item for div[@class="-title"]//span[@class="salary"] query of class XpathSelector
```

Как его поймать?

Comment: `except weblib.error.DataNotFound:`

или

`except DataNotFound:`

Comment: Я пробовал и это тоже. Нет - всё равно пролетает на else.

Answer (score 2):

Хм, выяснилось, что нужно ставить try в другом месте. Как-то так:

```
sal = i.select('div[@class="-title"]//span[@class="salary"]')
try:
    sal = int(sal.text())
except IndexError:
    jobinfo.update({'salary': 'Null'})
    print 'ok null'
except ValueError:
    jobinfo.update({'salary': 'Null'})
    print 'ok null'       
else:
   jobinfo.update({'salary':sal})
```